# Use Boost strand in conjunction with std::future

Tags: c++, lambda, boost-asio

I have come across a use case where I would like to use a Boost strand in conjunction with a std::future.

To reduce code duplication, I have written a generic function which will post a task to a boost strand and return the future.

```
// Some definitions first...
typedef boost::asio::io_service::strand     cb_strand;
typedef std::shared_ptr< cb_strand >        cb_strand_ptr;
```

The code looks something like:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class Task>
auto post_future_to_strand(cb_strand_ptr apStrand, Task task)
{
    using return_type = decltype(task());

    auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<return_type>>();
    auto future = promise->get_future();

    apStrand->wrap
        (
            [promise, task]()
            {
                try
                {
                    promise->set_value(task());
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    // LOG ERROR ...


                    // NOTE: Exceptions can be thrown when setting the exception!
                    try
                    {
                        promise->set_exception(std::current_exception());
                    }
                    catch (...)
                    {
                        //LOG ERROR ...
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    return future;
};
```

I then hoped to post a future to a strand as presented in the following example:

```
std::future<int> f = post_future_to_strand(m_apStrand, std::bind(&foo::bar, this))
std::cout << "foo::bar() -> int is " << f.get() << std::endl;
```

Unfortunately, I get a runtime exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
what():  std::future_error: Broken promise
Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)
```

Having read the docs, I think I understand what a broken promise is and how the situation arises; however, I feel like I am capturing the promise in the lambda so all should be well.  I am a newcomer to this world of lambdas, so perhaps my understanding is amiss.

- Ubuntu Zesty
- GCC 6.3 (configured for C++14 with cmake)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrap the task, but you never post it. Therefore, the wrapped task is immediately destructed, and with that the promise.

There's another pitfall, things only work if you run the io_service on a different thread than the one blocking for the future... Otherwise you have created a deadlock:

- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f41fc4cc15c71b90)</kbd>** deadlock

Now that you have multiple threads, you need to avoid the race-condition where the service exits before the task is posted in the first place.

> #### Bonus:
>
> I'd suggest a far simpler take on the wrapper:
>
> ```
> template <typename Task>
> auto post_future_to_strand(cb_strand_ptr apStrand, Task task)
> {
>     auto package = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task())()> >(task);
>     auto future  = package->get_future();
>
>     apStrand->post([package] { (*package)(); });
>     return future;
> }
> ```

#### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b4487e36f767155)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using cb_strand_ptr = boost::asio::strand*;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename Task>
auto post_future_to_strand(cb_strand_ptr apStrand, Task task)
{
    auto package = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task())()> >(task);
    auto future  = package->get_future();

    apStrand->post([package] { (*package)(); });
    return future;
}

struct Foo {
    boost::asio::strand s;
    cb_strand_ptr m_apStrand = &s;

    Foo(boost::asio::io_service& svc) : s{svc} {}

    void do_it() {
        std::future<int> f = post_future_to_strand(m_apStrand, std::bind(&Foo::bar, this));
        std::cout << "foo::bar() -> int is " << f.get() << std::endl;
    }

    int bar() { 
        return 42; 
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    auto lock = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(svc); // prevent premature exit

    std::thread th([&]{ svc.run(); });

    Foo foo(svc);
    foo.do_it(); 

    lock.reset(); // allow service to exit
    th.join();
}
```

Prints

```
foo::bar() -> int is 42
```

Comment: Thanks for that - short, sweet, and elegant solution. A bit embarrassed that I wasn't calling post(..) :/

One of my follow-up questions was to do with deadlocks.  There is a similar question on SO about such issues, but I didn't understand under what conditions a deadlock would arise. With your explanation, the problem is all clear now. Thanks again.